# How can I get the text from a class with no name?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is the HTML I am trying to get the text 'RCOVE12776' from

```
<span class="">SKU</span>
":  "
"RCOVE12776"
```

the code I am using to try and get it is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class=""]/[text()="SKU"]').text
```

I feel like I'm missing something very simple here, also there may be multiple to catch so I would need to find all the text from all the classes "" that contains SKU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over the original HTML code, use an attribute id instead of a class, and then use the driver to find the element with the id.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code to get required text:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[span[@class="" and .="SKU"]]').text.split(':')[-1]
```